# Export multiple table data to csv in c#.net using threading

Tags: c#, export-to-csv

I want to export multiple table records to an individual CSV file in c#.net.

say

a listbox which contains 10 tables. If I click table 1 then export to csv starts for that table. In the mean time I will click another table in the list box say table 2, then export to  csv should start for that table 2. kinda of multi-threading. Below is the code where I use to export to csv, but it is for one table only

```
public void exportToCSVfile(string fileOut)
        {
            // Connects to the database, and makes the select command.

            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=" + DataSource + ";User Id=" + UserId + ";Password=" + Password);
            string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + this.lbxTables.SelectedItem.ToString().ToUpper().Trim();
            OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(sqlQuery, conn);
            conn.Open();

            // Creates a SqlDataReader instance to read data from the table.
            using (OracleDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // Retrives the schema of the table.
                DataTable dtSchema = dr.GetSchemaTable();

                // Creates the CSV file as a stream, using the given encoding.
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileOut, false, this.encodingCSV))
                {

                string strRow; // represents a full row

                // Writes the column headers if the user previously asked that.
                if (this.chkFirstRowColumnNames.Checked)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(columnNames(dtSchema, this.separator));
                }

                // Reads the rows one by one from the SqlDataReader
                // transfers them to a string with the given separator character and
                // writes it to the file.
                MessageBox.Show("Export to CSV has started for the Table: " + this.lbxTables.SelectedItem.ToString().ToUpper().Trim());
                while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        strRow = "";
                        for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            strRow += Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(i)) + separator;
                        }
                        if (separator.Length > 0)
                            strRow = strRow.Substring(0, strRow.LastIndexOf(separator));

                        sw.WriteLine(strRow);
                    }
                }
                dr.Close();
                dr.Dispose();
            }

            // Closes the text stream and the database connenction.

            conn.Close();

            //// Notifies the user.
            MessageBox.Show("Export to CSV has completed for the Table: " + this.lbxTables.SelectedItem.ToString());
        }
```

Please help me out how can i do for multiple table data using threading

Comment: I don't envy you, good luck! NB: You don't need close or dispose is you have a using normally, that's the benefit of using a [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#vcwlkthreadingtutorialexample1creating) you will find a tutorial for threading in c#. Basicly you need to use your export method as thread method. It is good to keep handlers to all threads you will create.

To be more specific...
step 1) create class for exporter

```
public class CSVExport
{
    // This method that will be called when the thread is started
    public void exportToCSVfile(object fileOut)
    {
        ...
    }
};
```

in response to user choose table to export you run following

```
CSVExport obj = new CSVExport();
Thread t = new Thread (CSVExport.exportToCSVfile);
t.Start(oFileName);
```

You have to ensure that file names are unique and as I said before it is good to keep all thread handlers in a list.